# Geolib and getPreciseLocation through an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, geolocation

I have an array and I need to order the data of it by the distance of a specific point.
Knowing that `.sort()` won't work since I'm dealing with coordinates, I've been using a library called Geolib which has a function called `getPreciseLocation()` which is exactly what I need, but it doesn't seem to work while iterating through an array.
Here is the array containing the data I will be using.

Data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "Point": "27.1597268, 40.6646601"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "Point": "11.1640393, 49.648713"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "Point": "26.1539253, 42.6599287"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "Point": "21.1597268, 44.6646601"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "Point": "10.1640393, 43.648713"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "Point": "26.1539253, 61.6599287"
    }
]
```

The code I've been trying to use to iterate through the array.

```
let DistancesFromUserLocation = [];
this.state.Data.forEach(item => {
    DistancesFromUserLocation.push(geolib.getPreciseDistance({latitude: 30.1891168, longitude: 11.6226982}, item.Point))
})
```

As a disclaimer: I only need to get to receive the distance of each array object to a new array.
I've tried and researched many things and get around the solution, but just about thinking that I am getting to the solution, something would go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **push** the generated distance each iteration to `DistancesFromUserLocation` array.

```js
let DistancesFromUserLocation = [];
this.state.Data.forEach(item => {
    // push each distance to `DistancesFromUserLocation`
    DistancesFromUserLocation.push(
       geolib.getPreciseDistance(
           {latitude: 30.1891168, longitude: 11.6226982},
           item.Point
       );
    )
})
```

Only then you can use the `Array.sort()`.

```js
console.log(DistancesFromUserLocation.sort());
```

EDIT:
Check my working example here at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-platform-b29l6?file=/src/App.js:0-1302).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I got around to all night. It seems that I have pasted the wrong code when I should have pasted the one with the .push() method. Even with that, it doesn't work. It returns the **same** values:Array [
  3387103,
  3387103,
  3387103,
  3387103,
  3387103,
  3387103,
]

Comment: That's weird. I am using [`geolib v3.3.1` by manuelbieh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib) and it works seamlessly. Check my working example here at [Stackblitz](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-platform-b29l6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yeah, it is absolutely the output I want. I'm also using that version of Geolib but I'm really confused right now. It's kind of weird. ** EDIT ** : What's weirder, I wrote this code as a standalone to the .js I've been working, and it's working fine.

Comment: Maybe there's something weird happening outside of your code? Also, make sure that your `this.state.Data`'s Points are correct before looping it.